# Content directory with FilePathResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I put the file need to return in the content folder. If I want to return the file, what the path to use? Is there anyway that MVC can find reources in the content folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea what content folder you are talking about but if we suppose that it is some sub directory:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File(Server.MapPath("~/content/foo.txt"), "text/plain");
}
```

where `~` indicates the root of your web site.